# Ad-hoc retreival of data from SQL Server varbinary column

Tags: sql-server, varbinary

I would like to retreive some binary data from a `varbinary(max)` column in a SQL Server database for debugging purposes.

What is the easiest way to get this data into a local binary file, preferably without having to write a throw-away console application?

I have tried using SQL Server Management Studio (with the "results to file" option) but this outputs a hex encoded binary string to the file, rather than the raw binary data.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, but do you know about LINQPad? It's basically an application in which you can write "throw-away" C# applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found [this solution](http://www.bryansgeekspeak.com/2011/12/sql-server-2008-dumping-varbinary-data.html) with `bcp` command (run from command prompt):

```
c:\temp>bcp "select MYVARBINARYCOL from MYTABLE where id = 1234" queryout "c:\filename.pdf" -S MYSQLSERVER\MYINSTANCE -T

Enter the file storage type of field filedata [varbinary(max)]:
Enter prefix-length of field filedata [8]: 0
Enter length of field filedata [0]:
Enter field terminator [none]:

Do you want to save this format information in a file? [Y/n] n

Starting copy...

1 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total : 15 Average : (66.67 rows per sec.)
```

I used the -T option to use windows authentication to connect to the DB. If you use password auth, you'll need to use the -U and -P switches to specify a username and password.

But I also like [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) suggestion in [Robb Sadler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5899242/281048) and somehow prefer it.

Answer (score 7):

I can't think of any easier way to do this than a throw away bit of C#...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetBinaryDataToFile("Server=localhost;Initial Catalog=ReportServer;Integrated Security=true", "D:\\temp.dat");
    }

    public static void GetBinaryDataToFile(string connectionString, string path)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = "SELECT Sid FROM Users WHERE UserID = '62066184-8403-494E-A571-438ABF938A4F'";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        SqlBinary sqlBinary = dataReader.GetSqlBinary(0);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(path, sqlBinary.Value);
                    }

                    dataReader.Close();
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

This code has been tested using the Users.Sid column (which is of varbinary type) in a default installation of SQL Server wih Reporting Services.

Answer (score 4):

I loved the LinqPad suggestion. I tried it and had a query that spit out the binary to a file within 10 minutes. No VS Project, no build - and now the script is saved and I can pull it up anytime. So cool!

LinqPad script:

```
var g = from pd in Archives 
    where pd.ArchiveId == 123
    select pd;

var q = from p in printDocs
where p.DocumentId == g.SingleOrDefault().DocumentId
select p;

File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\temp.pdf", q.SingleOrDefault().Pdf.ToArray());
```

Comment: I don't get it. How does this work in LinqPad? Where is 'Archives' defined? Are you referencing some external libraries where your Linq-to-SQL/EntityFramework entities are defined?

Comment: I attached to my database and LinqPad built the Linq to Sql data class automatically. I then could access and use it. That is part of what makes it cool. It's a quick download - I recommend giving it a whirl. This was the only code I wrote.

Comment: @DanielFortunov  See the step-by-step instruction written by Atron Seige in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056050/script-to-save-varbinary-data-to-disk