# How can extract SQL Server Fulltext to a text file

Tags: sql, full-text-search, extract

I have basic SQL knowledge and wondering if it is possible to run a command or some type of script that will iterate through a query result and for each record, extract the fulltext data and save it to a text file on my local drive?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script to save varbinary data to disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056050/script-to-save-varbinary-data-to-disk)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer SaUce. Can fulltext data be extracted like any other column using the Select statement in the example script? In other words, can I simply use:
DECLARE IMGPATH CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT myFulltext from myTable

Answer (score 0):

You may use bcp utility :

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1000)
```

--  EXPORT ITEMS

```
SET @SQL = ' BCP dbo.ITEMS out '
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'C:\FOLDER\ITEMS.CSV -T -t; -c -C UTF-8 -S'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks chris. This would export everything in the table, all columns and also the fulltext, correct?  Can I limit it to export only the fulltext?

Comment: Yes everything. You could prepare a select statement. I usually create a view with desired fields and export it instead just to have a clear bcp syntax.