# SQL server to convert base64 data into a file

Tags: sql-server, save, base64

**Scenario :**

- I convert a pdf file to base64 and put it in an xml, and

**Problem :**

- when I receive the xml I will have to convert this base64 data back
  to the original pdf file using SQL Server and store it somewhere.

I
   found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056050/script-to-save-varbinary-data-to-disk) but could not figure out how to do it. 
This is
   what I have:

```
DECLARE 
    @SQLcommand VARCHAR(8000),
    @MyOriginalFile VARCHAR(8000),
    @RawData VARCHAR(8000)

SET @RawData = 'JVBERi0x etc'

SET @SQLcommand = 'bcp "SELECT @MyOriginalFile = @RawData" queryout "\\MY-SERVER\MySharedFolder\New.pdf" -T -n -S A70195\dev'

EXEC xp_cmdshell @SQLcommand
```

- I think I need to understand what does the -T -n -S A70195\dev mean.

  Can someone please help?

  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from SQL2005 I would use `VARBINARY(MAX)` data type for PDF content and `FOR XML ... , BINARY BASE 64` to convert binary values to `BASE64`:

```
-- VarBinary -> XML
DECLARE @PdfContent VARBINARY(MAX)
SET @PdfContent = 0x12345678

SELECT  @PdfContent AS BinaryContent
FOR XML RAW, BINARY BASE64
-- Output <row BinaryContent="EjRWeA==" />

-- XML -> VarBinary
DECLARE @PdfContentAsXML XML
SET     @PdfContentAsXML = N'<row BinaryContent="EjRWeA==" />'
SELECT  x.XmlCol.value('(@BinaryContent)', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS BinaryContentFromXml
FROM    @PdfContentAsXML.nodes('row') x(XmlCol)
-- Output 0x12345678
```

Comment: I've tried your code and I can see my binary data. Does it mean we can convert binary data back to the original pdf file and save it to disk?

Comment: I would use a table with a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column to store PDF content plus a column  `FileName NVARCHAR(260)` to store file name. If PDF content is bigger than ~ 1MB then I would use (after testing) FILESTREAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx). A FILESTREAM column will store the content in separate files on filesystem but not in data files of SQL Server database. Here you may find how to import / export PDF files in/from SQL Server DB: http://jahaines.blogspot.ro/2009/10/ssis-importing-binary-files-into.html .

Comment: Please see above Bogdan Sahlean. Thanks

Comment: @user1564533: Documentation for `bcp` utility is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).