# How to pull out data from varbinary(Max) in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, varbinarymax

Problem: I have to pull out data from varbinary columns in MS SQL (PDF).

I have used this script

```
DECLARE @SQLIMG VARCHAR(MAX),
    @IMG_PATH VARBINARY(MAX),
    @TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ObjectToken INT

DECLARE IMGPATH CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT csl_CompanyLogo from mlm_CSCompanySettingsLocalizations

OPEN IMGPATH 

FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @IMG_PATH 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @TIMESTAMP = 'd:\' + replace(replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar,getdate(),121),'-',''),':',''),'.',''),' ','') + '.bmp'

        PRINT @TIMESTAMP
        PRINT @SQLIMG

        EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
        EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @IMG_PATH
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TIMESTAMP, 2
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

        FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @IMG_PATH 
    END 

CLOSE IMGPATH
DEALLOCATE IMGPATH
```

From here [Script to save varbinary data to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056050/script-to-save-varbinary-data-to-disk)

But now i wonder, how can i make file names more readable? For example use records from id column.

P.s. should i place tsql tag?

Comment: What do you mean by readable? How do you want your filename to look? And where is this ID column you might want to use?

Comment: So for example: i have `FileName` column and `vabinary` column with files. I want to extract files from `varbinary` and name them as `FileName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new variable of the same type as your filename column at the top.

Change your cursor to select both the varbinary and the filename, and use your new filename variable.

Use the filename variable when setting the filename in your script, instead of the date.

Your script becomes:

```
DECLARE @SQLIMG VARCHAR(MAX),
    @IMG_PATH VARBINARY(MAX),
    @TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ObjectToken INT,
    @Filename varchar(max)

DECLARE IMGPATH CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
        SELECT csl_CompanyLogo, [filename] from mlm_CSCompanySettingsLocalizations

OPEN IMGPATH 

FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @IMG_PATH , @Filename

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @TIMESTAMP = 'd:\' + @Filename + '.bmp'

        PRINT @TIMESTAMP
        PRINT @SQLIMG

        EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
        EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @IMG_PATH
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TIMESTAMP, 2
        EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

        FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @IMG_PATH , @Filename
    END 

CLOSE IMGPATH
DEALLOCATE IMGPATH
```