# How to download a file from a varbinary column using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with SQL Server 2016. I have a table file_data which has a column **data** of `varbinary` type.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[file_data]
(
    [file_data_id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [file_name] [VARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,
    [description] [VARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [data] [VARBINARY](MAX) FILESTREAM  NOT NULL,
    [file_guid] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pk_file_data] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([file_data_id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [filestream],
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([file_guid] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [filestream]
GO
```

That **data** column stores 1 file usually a txt file. So this table has multiple rows.

How can I download file of any 1 row from the **data** column using T-SQL? I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What front end are you running the T-SQL from?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You can't get binary information out that way, at least not easily, its not designed for that. You would normally pull files from code.

Comment: try the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056050/script-to-save-varbinary-data-to-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT: I just re-read your question and I think I've got the issue wrong...

The line *So this table has multiple rows* hooked me...

If you want nothing more then to get the binary content of a table's column out to the file system, you might use `BCP` (see the linked answer and keep in mind, that this will not act under your account, so access rights and target directories might not be what you expect). But I would use some external tool, probably powershell, connect to the database and simply read the content to a file.

### I won't delete my former answer as it can help too.

I'm pretty sure, that T-SQL is the wrong tool for this. My answer might help you, it will at least show some principles...

A *BLOB column* (in your case `VARBINARY(MAX)`) is nothing more than a meaningless chain of bytes. SQL-Server has no idea how to interpret this as meaningfull data.

I use a simple string variable to *mockup* a file's content:

```
DECLARE @TestText VARCHAR(MAX)=
N'This is the first line
This is the second line';
```

--Now this string is casted to varbinary and assigned to a BLOB-variable.
--This is - in principles - what you've got within your column

```
DECLARE @YourFileStore VARBINARY(MAX)=CAST(@TestText AS VARBINARY(MAX));
SELECT @YourFileStore;
```

--This you get back

```
0x5468697320697320746865206669727374206C696E650D0A5468697320697320746865207365636F6E64206C696E65
```

--this is a HEX-string, where each two digits represent a character (the 54 is the `T`, the 68 the `h` and so on.
--Somewhere in the middle you'll find the sequence `0D0A`, which is the line break.
--As long as we know *how to interpret* the binary, we can simply re-cast it to the former type. This will get the former string back:

```
SELECT CAST(@YourFileStore AS VARCHAR(MAX));
```

--Reading this *line by line* will need a string-splitting at the line breaks.
--You did not state your SQL-Server's version. Here I use `OPENJSON` (needs v2016+).

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(CAST(@YourFileStore AS VARCHAR(MAX)),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'","') + '"]');
```

### When will this work for you:

This might work for you, if all BLOBs have the same content (in structure) and SQL-Server can use a simple `CAST` or `CONVERT` to achieve a meaningfull data type.

### When will this not work for you:

If the textfiles are not simple `UCS-2` (almost the same as `UTF-16`), which translates to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` or *plain ASCII*, which translates to `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

Any encoding (like `utf-8`), the wrong *endian* or ASCII >127 (look for *collations*) might return just rubbish.

### What you should do:

If this simple cast helps you to read the data - well - then your are a lucky one. If not, you should use another tool with more abilities in string handling.

You should **always store data in the appropriate type**. BLOBs are meant for data, where you **do not want to look inside** (like a picture). Your data should be stored in separate lines, with a common ID and a row number to re-create the full text.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. It work because the column contains text files.