# Best way to retrieve pdf attachments saved as varbinary(max) from SQL Server and save to a local drive using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have few thousands attachments saved in a SQL Server database with column datatype `varbinary(max)`. I want to retrieve all these files and save them to a local drive.

What is the best way to achieve that? I am not looking for code specifically but trying to understand all options so I can do this in C#.

Suggestions are appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can easily read the `varbinary(max)` column into a byte array (`byte[] attachment`) in C# and then save that to a file on disk - question is: do you have the **file name** to use stored in that database table, too??

Comment: Yes I do have all that..

Answer (score 1):

You can do any of the followings:

- Write a SQL script which will read the data from the table and save those to the disk. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4088007/218408) is how that can be done
- You can write a C# script which will connect to the Database, Read and store the data as a file to a disk

Use the Id of the table as part of the file name to make it unique if you are storing all the files to a single folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code.
Note, the namespace System.Data.SqlClient is not referenced by a .NET Core project by default as done by .NET Framework; you have to manually add the System.Data.SqlClient NuGet package to the project.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatbase;Integrated Security=True;";

var outputFolder = @"C:\temp\";

using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

var query = "select DocumentId, Contents from DocumentFile where ID >= 1234";
using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
cmd.Connection = conn;

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (!reader.HasRows) throw new Exception("No rows!");

while (reader.Read())
{
    var fileName = $"{reader["DocumentId"]}.pdf";
    var data = (byte[])reader["Contents"];
    if (data == null) throw new Exception("Contents is null");

    using var writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(outputFolder, fileName)));
    writer.Write(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is very similar to @dr9, but I faced an issue that was resolved after reading [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-binary-data) on learn.microsoft.com

In my code, I was missing the CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess parameter and this page makes a special mention to that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace DocExtractor
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var db = new SqlConnection();
            db.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCon"].ConnectionString;
            db.Open();
            string sqlString = @"SELECT Id, PdfData From Documents";
            // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.  
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlString,db);

            FileStream stream;
            // Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.  
            BinaryWriter writer;

            // Size of the BLOB buffer.  
            int bufferSize = 100;
            // The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.  
            byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];
            // The bytes returned from GetBytes.  
            long retval;
            // The starting position in the BLOB output.  
            long startIndex = 0;

            // The publisher id to use in the file name.  
            string pubID = "";

            // Open the connection and read data into the DataReader.  
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Get the publisher id, which must occur before getting the logo.  
                pubID = reader["Id"].ToString();

                // Create a file to hold the output.  
                stream = new FileStream(
                  "Id-" + pubID + ".pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

                // Reset the starting byte for the new BLOB.  
                startIndex = 0;

                // Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.  
                retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);

                // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.  
                while (retval == bufferSize)
                {
                    writer.Write(outByte);
                    writer.Flush();

                    // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.  
                    startIndex += bufferSize;
                    retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // Write the remaining buffer.  
                writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval);
                writer.Flush();

                // Close the output file.  
                writer.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }

            // Close the reader and the connection.  
            reader.Close();
            db.Close();
        }
    }
}
```